# Can the stack and data segments on the x86 ever overlap?

Tags: operating-system, x86, memory-segmentation, data-segment

I know that generally speaking data segments in x86 can overlap but can the stack and data segments overlap I am asking this cause generally they are quiet far from each other in illustration of data segments

Comment: Really? According to [some random picture I searched up](http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleZ.html) (heading "Z.3") the two segments are very near each other, with only BSS in between.

Comment: "Segments" are an implementation detail of 8086 Real Mode.  An ancient detail that I gladly forgot about 20 years ago but that keeps coming back in SO questions.  Sure, they can overlap on a 16-bit OS, or a bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Barbara,

In short, yes they can overlap quite easily.  Any segment can overlap another segment.  Please refer to this [explanation](http://wiki.osdev.org/Segmentation) for details explaining segmentation, it describes how they can overlap.